# how to remove displayed notification using cordova

Tags: cordova, localnotification

how can i remove notification which has been displayed(presend on phone bar) but not repspond by the user? using cordova 
https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications/

i check different method but didn't get any property or function of it. although when registering

```
window.plugin.notification.local.add({
    id:         String,  // A unique id of the notification
    date:       Date,    // This expects a date object
    message:    String,  // The message that is displayed
    title:      String,  // The title of the message
    repeat:     String,  // Either 'secondly', 'minutely', 'hourly', 'daily', 'weekly', 'monthly' or 'yearly'
    badge:      Number,  // Displays number badge to notification
    sound:      String,  // A sound to be played
    json:       String,  // Data to be passed through the notification
    autoCancel: Boolean, // Setting this flag and the notification is automatically cancelled when the user clicks it
    ongoing:    Boolean, // Prevent clearing of notification (Android only)
}, callback, scope);
```

you have an option of

```
  autoCancel: Boolean, // Setting this flag and the notification is automatically cancelled when the user clicks it
```

This is working but how can i removed using coding.

I tried cancel By id

```
function cancelLocalNotificationById(id){
        window.plugin.notification.local.cancel(id, function(){
            alert("cancel callback", id);
        });
    }
}
```

this will register in onTrigger. and cancel by id will run after 5 seconds

```
function onTrigger(){
 window.plugin.notification.local.ontrigger = function (id, state, json) {
            alert("onTrigger fired");
            alert(id);

                // Cancel alert after 5 seconds...
                timeouts.push(setTimeout(function(){
                    cancelLocalNotificationById(id);
                    alert(id);
                    //alert("cancel reslut"+cancel.status);
                },5000));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use *cancel* method to remove the notification by it's id. From the plugin documentation:

```
window.plugin.notification.local.cancel(ID, function () {
    // The notification has been cancelled
}, scope);
```

where *id* is simply the id of notification you want to dismiss.

As you mentioned *autoCancel* is to do the cancelling automatically **when user clicks the notification**. Without it being true, you need to cancel it from within Cordova while you handle the callback of that notification.

**Update**

As it turned out that you are using

```
new Date()
```

as *id* for notifications added, it is the cause since there is this restriction

> Note: On Android the notification id needs to be a string which can be
>   converted to a number. If the ID has an invalid format, it will be
>   ignored, but cancelling the notification will fail.

and the `new Date()` yields something like

```
Wed Jan 07 2015 14:16:10 GMT+0200 (FLE Standard Time)
```

which isn't convertible to number.

Comment: i have did this but notification still exists

Comment: on click removing the notification but cancel by id didn't

Comment: @MohammadFaizanKhan: can you show an example of the id you are using?

Comment: @MohammadFaizanKhan: Yes, I see, but what is the _id_ with what you initially create the notification? To say it other way, what is the parameter _id_'s value which you pass for _window.plugin.notification.local.add_?

Comment: yes id is the same wy which i register the notification in add. i have also alert it

Comment: id is acutally current date time (new Date())

Comment: i alerted the id of notification in onTrigger as you see above in code

Comment: @MohammadFaizanKhan: If you really use `new Date()` written like that, the problem is there. That yields _Wed Jan 07 2015 14:16:10 GMT+0200 (FLE Standard Time)_ for id which isn't convertible to integer as it should be for Android. There is this mentioned on documentation: `Note: On Android the notification id needs to be a string which can be converted to a number. If the ID has an invalid format, it will be ignored, but cancelling the notification will fail.`.

Comment: thanks a lot @sanfor. update the answer for future use. You save the day

Comment: Sure, please also mention the way you created it on your question for future reference!

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a bit of confusion of terms here. "Notification" is both used to denote the instruction to the operating system to schedule a series of repeating messages and it is used to refer to a single instance of those messages.

The autoCancel attribute is used to automatically remove a single instance of a notification message from the Android messaging bar and window when the users taps it to launch your app. If you set this to false, the app icon remains visible in those areas until the user erases it manually.

To answer the original question: there is no way with Katzer's plugin to erase the app icon associated with an instance of the notification other than the autoCancel attribute.